# In a database how to find connections between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database and it has lot of tables. I want to find column names from tables that link them to each other. So as to join them.

I simply want to know what columns are common between the tables so I will know how to go ahead and join them to get the desired result.

Is there a way to know how to find the column names similar or do I have to check each and every table?

This is for SQL Server 2008

Comment: You can find foreign key relations, that's all. Read the documentation!

Comment: You can look at sys.tables and sys.columns. But there is no guarantee that will find all columns that can be joined. You can also look at sys.foreign_keys to find explicit relationships.

Comment: other than explicit FK relationships, there's no way to guess if two columns CAN be related. just having the same name doesn't mean they're related.

Comment: Hopefully foreign keys will have been created.  If not; then you need to ask for a externally maintained Entity Relationship Diagram.  If they don't have one of those, then you're only place to look is prior code to see how joins were performed.  SQL server offers some diagramming for ERD as well if PK/FK relationships have been defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sys.foreign_keys` will contain information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) about the columns which are explicitly related as keys.

Aside from that, there is no *structural* relationship in the schema between any given pair of columns.  If any two columns on separate tables are *supposed* to be connected but aren't *actually* connected in the schema, that's more of a failure of the schema than anything else.

There is no mechanism which will reveal what columns the system's creators *intended* to be related but didn't actually relate.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is to look at column names if the FK method doesnt pan out.

```
SELECT c.name AS column_
, t.name AS table_

FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%userID%'
ORDER BY t.name
```